# How to make join where it shows data from other tables with the same id

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables: "Terceiros", "Morada_Terceiro" and " Contactos_Terceiros". What i want to do is, when a client(=terceiro) is inserted is attributed to it an address (=table Morada_Terceiro) and contacts(=table Contactos_Terceiros). The problem is, I tried INNER JOIN and when i added more than one address or contact for the same person it wouldn't list, so i tried LEFT JOIN and it showed the same client twice, but with the same information, then i tried RIGHT,FULL JOIN and none of them worked

```
//Tabela Terceiros 

    $sql="SELECT Terceiros.*, Email, Telefone, Telemovel, TipoC, Morada, Localidade, CodPostal FROM ((Terceiros INNER JOIN  Contactos_Terceiro on  Terceiros.Numero = Contactos_Terceiro.Numero ) INNER JOIN Morada_Terceiro on Terceiros.Numero = Morada_Terceiro.Numero )";
    if(isset($pesq))
        $sql.=" where Nome like '$pesq' ";
        $sql.=" limit $ini, $tp";
        $res=$lig->query($sql);
```

---

```
//Tabela Contactos_Terceiro

  $sql="SELECT  Contactos_Terceiro.*, Nome FROM  Contactos_Terceiro INNER JOIN Terceiros on (Terceiros.Numero =  Contactos_Terceiro.Numero)";
    if(isset($pesq))
    $sql.=" where Nome like '$pesq'";
    $sql.=" limit $ini, $tp";
    $res=$lig->query($sql);
```

---

```
//Tabela Morada_Terceiro

  $sql="SELECT Morada_Terceiro.*, Nome FROM Morada_Terceiro INNER JOIN Terceiros on (Terceiros.Numero = Morada_Terceiro.Numero)";
    if(isset($pesq))
        $sql.=" where Nome like '$pesq'";
    $sql.=" limit $ini, $tp";
    $res=$lig->query($sql);
```

---

```html
  // table Terceiros 
 $sql="SELECT * from Terceiros";
 if(isset($pesq))
  $sql.=" where Nome like '$pesq' ";
     $sql.=" limit $ini, $tp";
     $res=$lig->query($sql); 




// the query for the button 

<?php    
 $sql="SELECT Terceiros.*, Email, Telefone, Telemovel, TipoC, Morada, Localidade, CodPostal FROM ((Terceiros CROSS JOIN  Contactos_Terceiro on  Terceiros.Numero = Contactos_Terceiro.Numero ) CROSS JOIN Morada_Terceiro on Terceiros.Numero = Morada_Terceiro.Numero )";
$res=$lig->query($sql);          
while ($lin=$res->fetch_array()){ ?>   
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo$lin[Numero]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo$lin[Cliente]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[Fornecedor]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[NIF]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[Nome]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[Idsiliamb]; ?></td> 
  <td><?php echo$lin[Tipo]; ?></td>

        <td><a href=index.php?cmd=editer&Numero=<?php echo$lin[Numero];?> title="Editar"><img src='Imagens/edit.png' width="20" height = "20" ></a></td>
  <td><a href=index.php?cmd=delter&Numero=<?php echo$lin[Numero];?> title="Apagar" onclick="return confirm('Tem a certeza que deseja apagar este registo?');" ><img src='Imagens/delete.png' width="20" height = "20" ></a></td>
  <td><button data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#<?php echo$lin[Numero];?>" title="Visualizar" class="btn btn-default openBtn"><img src='Imagens/eye.png' width="20" height = "20" ><button></td>
      </tr> 
                                                                    <!-- Inicio do PopUp -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo $lin['Numero']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $lin['Nome']; ?></h4>
           </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="table-responsive">
                                                <div class="divTable blueTable">
                                                <div class="divTableHeading">
                                                <div class="divTableRow">
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Telefone</div>
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Telemovel</div>
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Email</div>
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Tipo</div>
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Morada</div>
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Localidade</div>
                                                    <div class="divTableHead">Codigo Postal</div>

                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="divTableBody">
                                                <div class="divTableRow">
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['Telefone']; ?></div>
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['Telemovel']; ?></div>
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['Email']; ?></div>
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['TipoC']; ?></div>
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['Morada']; ?></div>
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['Localidade']; ?></div>
                                                    <div class="divTableCell"><?php echo $lin['CodPostal']; ?></div>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>

              </div>
         </div>
         </div>
            </div>
                                         <!-- Fim do PopUp -->
        
      
<?php  } ?>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the structure of these three tables and the relationship between them with sample data?

Comment: i edited the post, you can check it out now xx

Comment: Please, show us the query you are using and we will be able to help you find the error.

Comment: i did, its above the question

Comment: Your question does not contain SQL queries. It contains PHP code with embedded SQL that is hard to read. And the PHP code is essentially irrelevant if you are looking for a SQL solution.

Comment: $sql="SELECT Terceiros.*, Email, Telefone, Telemovel, TipoC, Morada, Localidade, CodPostal FROM ((Terceiros INNER JOIN  Contactos_Terceiro on  Terceiros.Numero = Contactos_Terceiro.Numero ) INNER JOIN Morada_Terceiro on Terceiros.Numero = Morada_Terceiro.Numero )";

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, when you tried

```
Terceiros INNER JOIN  Contactos_Terceiro INNER JOIN Morada_Terceiro
```

there might not be data present in any one of these three tables and that is why you got empty result set.

LEFT JOIN in place of INNER JOIN is the best option to go with and I think you got the correct result trying that. Let's say you have two contact records C1, C2 for user U1, the LEFT JOIN would map U1 against both C1 and C2 and that's why you get U1 twice.

You can try the following steps:

  1. Query only the Users (Terceiros) table without any JOINS for
      displaying the first page with Eye button.

  2. Once the user clicks the Eye button, shoot the query with LEFT JOIN for
      the particular user and now you will get n records based on the
      number of contacts present for the particular User using which you
      can display the different contacts present for the User

Comment: I tried what you suggested but nothing really changed, is there any way that i could show my code, so you could see where im failing at least?

Comment: You can update the original post to show what you tried. But, did you try "select * from terceiros" instead of  query with join..? If so, that should have solved your issue with first page...then, we can look into eye button functionality..

Comment: I did! And then i added the query with the join for the eye button, and left the files "Morada_Terceiro" and "Contactos_Terceiro" the way they were and nothing happened. im gonna update the post rn

Comment: I think variable $lin is assigned wrongly...it should have the output of previous query i guess...

Comment: how? how to you suggest me to do it?

Comment: while executing this line $lin=$res->fetch_array(), $res is assigned with the JOIN query. Change that and assign $res = "SELECT * from Terceiros" instead of JOIN query and this should solve your first page issue.

Comment: I did that and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is doable. Let's say I am Alex, I have Mary and John as contacts and I have London and Bristol as my addresses. What recordset do you want returned?

Alex | Mary | London

Alex | John | London

Or

Alex | Mary | London

Alex | Mary | Bristol

I do not think it is what you want. 
The addresses and contacts data sets seem to be unrelated. Whatever SQL you apply, you can only get their Cartesian product.

I think you need two recordsets displayed in two screen tables.

Comment: All of those tables are related, thats exactly what i tried to do with the querys above the question. What i to show is Alex | Mary | London and Alex | John | Bristol

Comment: In you data both Addresses (London, Bristol) and Contacts (Mary, John) are related to clients (Alex). In order to achieve what you suggesting you need to have contact relate to Clients and Addresses to Contacts. Then your second join will be between second and third table

Comment: Isnt that what i did on the first query?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you second join should be something like

```
SELECT Terceiros.*, Email, Telefone, Telemovel, TipoC, Morada, Localidade, CodPostal 
FROM Terceiros 
   INNER JOIN  Contactos_Terceiro on Terceiros.Numero = Contactos_Terceiro.Numero 
   INNER JOIN Morada_Terceiro on Contactos_Terceiro.USE_CONTACT_ID_HERE = Morada_Terceiro.THIS_SHOULD_BE_CONTACT_ID_FIELD
```

Comment: but the tables " Morada_Terceiro" and "Contactos_Terceiro" are not related

Comment: Even tho i knew it wouldn't work, i still tried, needless to say it returned as an error